# Number of the positive integers up to $\sqrt x $ generated by the prime factors of $x$.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

Let $x$ be a natural number and $F_x$ be the set of distinct prime factors of $x$. One more let $\langle F_x \cup \{ 1 \} \rangle$ be multiplicative semigroup generated by the set. Then, the problem what I ask is that the cardinality of the set $$ \{   n \mid n\in \langle F_x \cup \{ 1 \} \rangle , \ n \leq \sqrt x  \} .$$

It would be siffice to prove for primorials, the cardinality is less than
$$   \log_2 x \log_3 x \log_5 x \cdots \log_p x ,  \ \ \text{for a primorial }\ x=2\cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot \cdots \cdot p.$$
Now, if we use that $\pi(n)\sim n/ \log n$, the product brings so big estimation, whilst it seems to $o( \sqrt x / \log x).$

Are there some methods or papers to find an efficient estimation of the cardinality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tea almost ready; you are asking, for example, how many triples $r,s,t$ satisfy
$$ 2^r 3^s 5^t \leq W.   $$
Take the logarithm,
$$  r \, \log 2 + s \, \log 3 + t \, \log 5 \leq \log W. $$
Using the lower left rule, the number of solutions with $r,s,t \geq 0$ integers is well approximated by the volume of the simplex being described over the reals, that being
$$  \frac{1}{3!} \frac{\log W}{\log 2} \frac{\log W}{\log 3} \frac{\log W}{\log 5}    $$

Meanwhile, if $P$ is a primorial with largest prime factor $p,$ the Prime Number Theorem, in the version with Chebyshev's first function, says 
$$ \log P \approx p.  $$

Other than that, specific estimates for the most useful things in Rosser and Schoenfeld (1962). Two books with lots of estimates are [HANDBOOK](http://books.google.com/books/about/Handbook_of_Number_Theory_I.html?id=XT1-HjeXFgYC) which actually has two volumes, and   [ALGORITHMIC](http://books.google.com/books/about/Algorithmic_Number_Theory_Efficient_algo.html?id=iJx1lP9ZcIkC), just the one volume as far as I know. And there is always Hardy and Wright, which has the advantage of explaining things.

Tutorial: the lower left rule, no consistent name, is just the idea that, in the $x,y$ plane for example, we can identify a lattice square of side one with the (integer) $(x,y)$ point in its lower left corner. So, to approximate the number of such integer lattice points in some finite body, a calculation of the area of the body is a good guess; furthermore, with extra care, strict lower and upper bounds for the count can be constructed. The best known example is probably to estimate the number of integer pairs $(x,y)$ such that $x^2 + y^2 \leq A.$ A good estimate is $\pi A^2,$ the area of the disk.